# SQLAlchemy: Trying to extract distinct values from a column

Tags: python, sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this customer model:

```
class Customer(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer,unique=True,nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80),nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(200))
    phone_no = db.Column(db.String(10))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    right_sph = db.Column(db.String(5))
    right_cyl = db.Column(db.String(5))
    right_axis = db.Column(db.String(5))
    right_vision = db.Column(db.String(5))
    left_sph = db.Column(db.String(5))
    left_cyl = db.Column(db.String(5))
    left_axis = db.Column(db.String(5))
    left_vision = db.Column(db.String(5))
    near = db.Column(db.String(5))
    refered_by = db.Column(db.String(50))
    frame_cost = db.Column(db.Integer)
    lens_cost = db.Column(db.Integer)
    total_amt = db.Column(db.Integer)
    discount = db.Column(db.Integer)
    payable_amt = db.Column(db.Integer)
    advance_amt = db.Column(db.Integer)
    balance_amt = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I'm trying to extract all unique the values column `refered_by`. So for that I'm running this query:

```
customer_refered_by = Customer.query.with_entities(Customer.refered_by).distinct()
```

Now this query is not returning me a list of the entries, instead it's returning me the SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer.refered_by AS customer_refered_by
FROM customer
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what is it that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need to iterate over the query result (`for cust in customer_refered_by:print(x)` or call its `.all()` method to get a list of results.

Comment: Thankyou, I understood what I should have been doing.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks right:

```
customer_refered_by = Customer.query.with_entities(Customer.refered_by).distinct()
for entry in customer_refered_by:
    print(entry.refered_by)
```

Or to just quickly get it into a list:

```
distinct_referrers = [x.refered_by for x in customer_refered_by]
```